# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

porque não funciona?

```
$('#chatEnvia').click(function() {
  if ($("#chatEscrita").val() !== "") {
    $.post("inc_chatEnvia.php", {
      acesso: "ok",
      msg: $("#chatEscrita").val(),
      de: $("#de").val(),
      para: $("#para").val()
    });
    $("#chatEscrita").val("");

    $("#chatEnvia").Attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
    $("#chatEnvia").Attr('data-target', '#chatVazio');

  }
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Attr is not a function

```
$("#chatEnvia").Attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
$("#chatEnvia").Attr('data-target', '#chatVazio');
```

Comment: Tente `attr`, com letra minúscula.

Comment: @VictorStafusa kkkk Deu certo!...rsrs Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chamadas de funções são case sensitive, no seu exemplo, você está utilizando ".Attr()", com letra maíscula:

```
 $("#chatEnvia").Attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
```

Tente utilizar com letra minúscula:

```
$("#chatEnvia").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
```

Documentação: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

OBS: Todas as funções jQuery seguem um padrão lowerCamelCase, ou seja, a letra inicial sempre será minúscula. Mais informações: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase